# How do I find the equation of a logarithmic spiral (in polar form) passing through a certain amount of points?

Tags: logarithms, polar-coordinates, regression

Let's say I have the necessary amount of points that are needed to find an equation of a logarithmic spiral (in polar form) passing through them. How would I use them to find said equation?

Comment: Just find the values of $a$ and $b$ in $r = a (\theta - b)$.

Comment: How would I solve for the values of 2 unknowns?

Comment: The same way you fit a line (slope plus intercept) to two or more data points.  Look it up.

Comment: That's why I'm asking the question here. I know how to do a linear regression line or a quadratic regression equation, but I don't know how to set one up for a logarithmic spiral.

Comment: I haven't been able to find anything on the topic anywhere else.

Comment: Just consider $\theta$ to be $x$ and $r$ to be $y$.  Plot on a traditional rectangular graph and fit according to the methods you say you know how to do.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work

Comment: I need to know how to set up the system of equations. I know how to set up the system of equations for a linear regression and a quadratic regression equation, but not one for a logarithmic spiral in polar form.

Comment: Ahmed:  The equations *ARE THE SAME*.

Answer (score 0):

These two plots are of the *SAME* data:

[image]

and

[image]

The top is $(x,y)$ and the bottom is $(\theta,r)$.

Fitting such data is *IDENTICAL*!!